# Angular ng serve leads to: An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace

Tags: angular

I try to serve an angular (9.1.12) application with `ng serve --configuration=production` local to test the application in production mode. I receive the error: `Angular ng serve leads to An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace.` Any ideas what the issue might be?

**My angular.json**

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "port": 4300,            
        "browserTarget": "employee-platform:build"
   },
   "configurations": {
      "production": {
          "browserTarget": "employee-platform:build:production"
      }
   }
},
```

Comment: do you have an `environments.prod.ts` file as well?

Comment: Yes i also have the file `environment.prod.ts` in the directory `environments`.

Comment: do you have `configurations` sections under `projects > ... > build` as well as `projects > ... > serve` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a configuration section under `build` object:

```
"build": {
      ...
   },
   "configurations": {
      "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          ...
      }
   }
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was `prod` instead of `production` defined in build for whatever reason...

Comment: ah, yes... that would be an issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

similar to the "serve" please check in the "build" object and check for "configuration" some thing like below,

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

where in the src/environments/environment.prod.ts file,

we have to set production to true

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```